# Склонение имен собственных

Tags: имена-собственные

Подскажите, пожалуйста, склоняется ли фамилия КУЦЕНОК, в данном случае это мужчина...

Answer (score 3):

Фамилия склоняется, вариант склонения надо уточнять у носителя. 
Хотя в данном случае я не вижу причин для склонения без выпадения беглой: "Куценок-Куценока" - это что-то марсианское. 
Но воля носителя в данном случае - закон. 
В отношении словаря "дающего нормативные рекомендации для каждого слова".
Не решит он даже малой толики проблем. 
Ну сколько уж твердили миру, что фамилии Жемчужина(ж), Смородина(ж) имеют параллельные варианты склонений. Фамилии Дарвин, Чаплин, Кронин склоняются в зависимости от национальной принадлежности, Скобец, Вагина - исходя из принципа благозвучия, Нуждец, Казбец, Кошток - фонетических предпочтений  и т.д.

Comment: Что значит "воля носителя это закон"? Меня убеждал секретарь, что фамилия гендиректора не склоняется, Вы об этом?..

Comment: Ольга, А какая фамилия-то у директора???
В общем-то об этом, но применительно к другой ситуации. 
"Воля носителя" имеет место: а) при выборе **варианта** склонения, когда возможны варианты; б) елси нормативность склонения определяется происхождением фамилии; в)в части ударения; и г) в случаях, когда нормативный вариант склонения приводит к неблагозвучию.   
Вроде всё. Во всех остальных случаях никаких секретарш и начальников у грамматики русского языка не существует. Если гендиректор - мужчина и не француз, то фамилия его почти наверняка склоняется.

Answer (score 2):

Мужские фамилии склоняются: Куценок, Куценка, Куценку, Куценком, о Куценке

Answer (score 2):

Не буду повторять правильный предыдущий ответ, а дополню его формулировкой из "Грамоты.ру":"*Склонение ряда фамилий (как в единственном, так и во множественном числе) оказывается затруднительным из-за неясности, должна ли в них сохраняться беглость гласных по образцу омонимичных им или похожих по внешнему виду нарицательных существительных (Кравеца или Кравца — от Кравец, Журавеля или Журавля — от Журавель, Мазурока или Мазурка — от Мазурок и т. п.).
Разрешение таких затруднений не может быть обеспечено правилами, для этого необходим словарь фамилий, дающий нормативные рекомендации для каждого слова*".
"